# Windows 8 Explorer hides the system partition of another disk

Tags: windows-8, partitioning, windows-explorer

I have a another disk attached by SATA on the motherboard and there are two partitions inside, one is a **system partition**, another one is **logical disk**.

I can't view the system partition by using Windows 8 Explorer, it hides this partition. I *can* use "easeus partition master" to view the directory structure.

How do I show this partition in Windows 8 Explorer?

Comment: From Disk Management (Run / diskmgmt.msc), can you see if the partition has a drive letter assigned to it? If not, assign one and check in Explorer.

Comment: If you can see the directory structure through Easeus Partition manager then please take a screenshot and upload it on imgur.com and then post the link here in the post or as a comment. Also check in the partition manager that partition has assigned a letter or not as @Karan suggested you, you can see it in Easeus partition manger too and can assign a drive letter too.